# Setting Button FlatStyle in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, styles

I have just been learning about how styles and control templates in WPF can affect the appearance of buttons,

I'm trying to set the Button's FlatStyle, in the resources I've seen I can't find anything that tells me how I can do this, in Windows Forms this is set through `FlatStyle = Flat`.

How would one do this in WPF?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wpf flat button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064185/wpf-flat-button)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The `ToolBar` class defines a `Style` that makes `Button`s look flat. An example of using it is:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"/>
```

This also works for a `ToggleButton` when using `ToggleButtonStyleKey`.

WPF lets you completely restyle controls to make them look like whatever you want, which is why it doesn't have such a specific `FlatStyle` property on the `Button` control.

Comment: Which is more correct? To create a style for Button that mimics the ToolBar.ButtonStyle, or just use the code you've provided. Thanks Ed

Comment: Depends on your scenario I think. You can also "derive" a style from the ToolBar Button style by using the Style.BasedOn property.

Comment: In a pinch, this works pretty well. It is nice to use for a WPF Button control with an image as the sole content, as the image now will not shift up one pixel when you click and hold on the button. Thanks Kent.

Comment: That's a good start. Unfortunately, WPF's toolbar button seems to show being focused in a way that can easily be confused with a "checked" toggle button (in fact, it looks a lot like a graphics bug, where the hover state is not correctly reset upon leaving the control) :-/

Comment: Just noticed - setting the button's `Focusable` property to `false` will fix that, though. (Note that the button should still be reachable with keyboard shortcuts - it's just not included in the tab order, which is generally not something expected of a toolbar button.)

Answer (score 25):

Add the following to your Window/Page resources:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" TargetType="Button"></Style>
```

It will apply the flat style to all buttons in that styles scope.