# Border on hover, Button, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [wpf flat button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064185/wpf-flat-button)
>   [Setting Button FlatStyle in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697381/setting-button-flatstyle-in-wpf)

I'm trying to do what Microsoft does allways for their apps that button are like images/labels before hover.

Ex: 
[alt text http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/3981/hovere.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/3981/hovere.png)

```
                hovered                                  normal view
```

Comment: Here is a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697381/setting-button-flatstyle-in-wpf, also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064185/wpf-flat-button

Answer (score 0):

You can write a new control template for the button you can look at the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) or this completely random [example](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html) I've found on Google.