# Setting button flat style programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I want to give a button a flat style programmatically when certain conditions occur.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199424/how-to-set-the-style-programatically) shows how I can set a style to a control programmatically, having already defined it in XAML.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697381/setting-button-flatstyle-in-wpf) shows that a flat button style already exists, so it is not necessary to create one in XAML.

`ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey` returns a `ResourceKey`, and the corresponding style is not defined in my window (it's in ToolBar). How do I use it in code to set the style programmatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As an alternative, you can try this:

`XAML`

```
<Button Name="FlatButton" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Test" />
```

`Code behind`

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FlatButton.Style = (Style)FindResource(ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a workaround that works. Add a style based on `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey` to `Window.Resources` as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" TargetType="Button" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then, in code, refer to it as per first link in this question:

```
button.Style = this.Resources["MyStyle"] as Style;
```

I'd prefer to have a code-only solution (no XAML) for this, but this works just as well.