# Using StaticResource and x:Static in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind, markup-extensions

I like [this flat button style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/697391/1997232):

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" BorderThickness="0" ... />
```

Trying to create such button in code behind:

```
var button = new Button
{
    Style = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey"), // wrong
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(0),
    ...
};
```

Will throw:

> An exception of type 'System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey' resource not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your working code, it should look like this:

```
Style = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource(ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey)
```

In other words, ditch the quotes. `ButtonStyleKey` is not the name, that's the static property that returns a string with the right name.